function to return number of characters in n line of a file return always those of line 2 in c
the function is supposed to return the length of a line specified by the 2nd argument
but the result is either 0 or the one in the 2nd line whatever n may be:
int line_length(const char *filename, int n)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    int len = 0;

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
        return -1;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n')
           /*  if (c = EOF)  // I removed these couple of lines, otherwise it 
                return 0; */ // yields always 0 since I THINK EOF always pops 
        n--;                 // once the line is finished
    }
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        len++;
    return len;
}

I removed these couple of lines, otherwise it
yields always 0 since I THINK EOF always pops
once the line is finished

Did you really have the line if ( c = EOF)?  That does not compare c to EOF.

if (c = EOF) Didn't your compiler show some warning about this line? Something about an assignment in a condition? This line actually assigns EOF to c and then the whole expression evaluates to EOF which is used as true value for the condition. That means you change c and the condition is always true.

Unrelated: This will get stuck if the last line in the file doesn't end with \n and n > 1.

Your n-- in inside the 2nd while loop. You want it inside the 1st while only.

This example is a strong argument for always using {} around your loop body.  By commenting out lines, you have put n-- into the loop.

Also a strong argument to crank up your compiler warnings.

Thank you, from now on I`m going to take more care about commenting out. I am deeply sorry for troubling you for this triffle  of a == test that a untoothed kid would have noticed. Also I want to say apologetically that I won't crank up the warnings because I don't want to read infinite poetry when programming. Finally I am tempted to use always {

{} in a single statement body. But I will give myself other opportunity.

Tip: If you open the file before the function call and pass the open FILE* as the parameter instead of filename, you avoid making the function call to begin with if the file fails to open (provided you adequately validate your open)  E.g. if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL) { mylen = line_length(fp, n); } or if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) { /* handle error */ } mylen = line_length(fp, n);-- Up to you.

The bug in the code was with the line:
if (c = EOF)
which should have read
if (c == EOF)
I uncommented the code, fixed this error, and it then worked for me in a test program.
